# How to kill/close log files that are open through lsof grep deleted?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, grep, lsof

I have a deleted a large log file from our servers. so I executed this command to validate.

```
lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'
```

[image]

and this showed up.

how can I permanently delete the results fo this lsof?  I need to recliam the needed space on our hardrive

Comment: Have you tired restarting  postgres?

Comment: @gmck I tried executing sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop but the file still persists/results still persists

Answer (score 2):

looks like pid `20583` is keeping open the file. So search for it

`ps aux | grep 20583`

See what process is holding it open and restart the process or kill it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a production system, just restart/kill postgres.

I'll check later for your answer, because there's a way to empty these files if you can't restart the application right now and you REALLY need the disk space urgently, but I wouldn't recommend it from the start.